# select susbtring

Tags: t-sql

I would like to discard everything after second underscore
for example,

`R5504572C_TCHC001_171463_PDF`

I would like to get

`R5504572C_TCHC001`

in a sql server query. I tried and was able to get `R5504572C` but I am looking to get `R5504572C_TCHC001`

```
select distinct left(JCFNDFUF2, charindex('_', JCFNDFUF2) - 1) AS LeftString
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have it:

```
select distinct LEFT(JCFNDFUF2, CHARINDEX('_', JCFNDFUF2, CHARINDEX('_', JCFNDFUF2) + 1) - 1) AS LeftString
```

You first call `CHARINDEX` to find the first '_' and then use that index + 1 as start location for the next call of `CHARINDEX`. If you needed to find the 5th '_', things would start to get ugly. :P

The column name is "JCFNDFUF2", seriously? :O

Answer (score 0):

just use start position

```
select distinct left(JCFNDFUF2, charindex('_', JCFNDFUF2, charindex('_', JCFNDFUF2))+1) - 1) AS LeftString
```

[CHARINDEX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I want to note that if the second `'_'` is always in the same position, then you can simply use:

```
select distinct left(JCFNDFUF2, 17)
```

You only have one example, but it sort of suggests a canonical naming scheme for the values -- and such a scheme would often have fixed width components.

EDIT:

You can also do this using `parsename()`, assuming that there are no commas in the components:

```
select distinct parsename(replace(JCFNDFUF2), '_', 4) + parsename(replace(JCFNDFUF2), '_', 3)
```