# Select a Substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, charindex

I found this question and answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932444/select-susbtring/26932611#26932611) website which is related to my question.

Except that my problem is that I need to display the information after the "-".

For example, it currently displays `7 - Net 7`, `14 - Net 14`, `9101 - Net 14`, `1 - COD` and so on.

I just want it to display the part after the "-".
For instance, I would like it to just display `Net 7` or `Net 14` or `COD`.

If I do this:

> select distinct right([C].[CustomerTermsCode], charindex(' - ', [C].[CustomerTermsCode]) + 4) AS RightString

It only displays the information before the "-".

Please help me.

Comment: Are you also using Microsoft SQL-Server?

Comment: Yes, I am using Microsoft SQL.

Comment: what is the purpose of adding 4 to the char index after you find the location of '-'?  I could see adding 1 to account for the space, but adding 4 skips over most of what is to the right in the first place.

Comment: @JoshGivens I thought I would have to do that in order to give it enough space to disply the "Net" part

Comment: No, or at least I don't think so.  try running your code without the +4 and let me know what happens.

Comment: You'll want to consider the length of the field value, since it seems the number of characters after the "-" can vary.

Comment: @TabAlleman wouldn't he not need to since he's using the right function which only needs a starting point to display the substring from?

Comment: No, the second argument of the RIGHT function is the number of characters from the right-bound of the string that the function will return, not a starting point.   What you're suggesting would be true if he were using the SUBSTRING function.

Comment: it sounds like he'd be better of using the SUBSTRING function, his arguments would just be the same select field, the same char index, and the length of the original select field minus the char index.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using substring, because the length before the dash changes.

```
select distinct substring([C].[CustomerTermsCode], charindex(' - ', [C].[CustomerTermsCode])+3,50) AS RightString
```

Comment: When I do that code I get this error
"select distinct substring([C].[CustomerTermsCode], charindex(' - ', [C].[CustomerTermsCode])+ 3,50) AS RightString" 

I also edited the code because I was getting a parenthesis error, I changed it to this:
 select distinct substring([C].[CustomerTermsCode], charindex(' - ', [C].[CustomerTermsCode])+ 3,50) AS RightString

Comment: That should work. Yea, when I pasted I got one extra parenthesis there.

Comment: sorry, I meant to say I get this error:
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

Comment: Is there nulls in the data?

Comment: Hey Autsin, were you able to get it to work correctly?

Comment: I ended up not having to use this, thanks for your help.